Odd transparent note icon on Ubuntu desktop after screen capture
It seems that, after pressing print-screen / screen capture while in Ubuntu client, a transparent icon sometimes appears at a random spot near the center of the Ubuntu desktop.
When I move the mouse close to the icon, the "chases" the icon until it literally goes out-of-sight off the screen's lower edge.  On many occasions, the icon appears and persists (can not be moved), at the top-left of the desktop.
While the icon is present, I cannot interact with items that are a "layer" below. IOW any application that is opened full-screen, as click-events are apparently intercepted by the icon / not detected by the underlying application.  Oddly, clicking has no effect on the transparent icon (doesn't open, etc.)
Questions:

What does this icon represent?  I was thinking clipboard.
Regardless of what it is, how do I get rid of it, without restarting the Ubuntu client?

Thank you!

